# After updating to latest telerik web ui, the ui is not function properly

Tags: asp.net, ajax, telerik

I am using .Net Framework 4.6 to build a web portal. Which is running at Windows 2016 and IIS 10. Previously, the UI can work. The previous version of telerik.web.ui.dll and telerik.web.ui.skins.dll is 2016.1.225.40. The updated version is 2023.2.714.45.
I have updated to latest Telerik web ui in my web portal using telerik visual studio extension. However, after updating, the web ui is not function properly.

I have attached the video for your comparison.

https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/pkhs6wbq0ofdtj6eialvc/UI-not-responding-after-applied-latest-telerik-web-ui-002.zip?rlkey=x9j3gb55zp722pw56037in9ib&dl=0

Comment: a detail about the environment (e.g. are you using Sitefinity) and the telerik web ui version (both previous and the upgraded one) might help specifying the problem. also, the link can't be opened without google account.

Comment: Not understand why it is voted to be closed. As it only focus on the UI problem of the updated dll. And video is attached for reference.

Comment: Changed to dropbox. If need other links for file. Please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: It is not very clear from the videos what the problem is. My advice is to capture with Fiddler Jam the working and non-working environment and to share it here or in a support ticket at Telerik.com. You can also check for any JavaScript errors on the page.

Comment: from 2016 to 2023, that was quite the leap. i suspect there are breaking changes, you should double check each subsequent version's change logs. the easiest way as Rumen mentioned, check the console logs. it may shed which endpoint or relevant javascript is missing.